# Post option text instead of value in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to post the data like USA and Florida instead of numbers (1 and 1). I tried to change `.value` to text but the code was not working.

This for filter city and state based on country but I have to update database with country and state name, currently I am getting values only, is there anyway to fix this?

**DB structure**

```
INSERT INTO `case_category` (`id`, `category`) VALUES
(1, 'USA'),
(2, 'China'):

INSERT INTO `case_sub_category` (`id`, `sub_category`, `category_id`) VALUES
(1, 'Florida', 1),
(2, 'Guangdong', 2),
(3, 'Sichuan', 2);
```

**loadData.php**

```
$loadType=$_POST['loadType'];
$loadId=$_POST['loadId'];

if($loadType=="subCat"){
    $sql="select id,sub_category from case_sub_category where category_id='".$loadId."' order by sub_category asc";
}else{
    $sql="select id,sub_sub_category from case_sub_sub_category where sub_category_id='".$loadId."' order by sub_sub_category asc";
}
$res=mysql_query($sql);
$check=mysql_num_rows($res);
if($check > 0){
    $HTML="";
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $HTML.="<option value='".$row['id']."'>".$row['1']."</option>";
    }
    echo $HTML;
}
?>
```

**Selector**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="request_type_c"  onchange="selectsubSubCat(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option value="-1">Select Category</option>
                <?php
                while($rowCategory=mysql_fetch_array($resCategory)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rowCategory['id']?>"><?php echo $rowCategory['category']?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="request_type_c_sub"  id="subCat_dropdown" onchange="selectsubCat(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                <option value="-1">Select Sub Category</option>
            </select>
            <span id="subCat_loader"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="request_type_c_sub_sub" id="subSubCat_dropdown">
                <option value="-1">Select Sub Sub Category</option>
            </select>
            <span id="subSubCat_loader"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**AJAX**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function selectsubSubCat(Category_id){
        if(Category_id!="-1"){
            loadData('subCat',Category_id);
            $("#subSubCat_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Category</option>");   
        }else{
            $("#subCat_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Sub Category</option>");
            $("#subSubCat_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Sub Sub Category</option>");       
        }
    }

    function selectsubCat(subCat_id){
        if(subCat_id!="-1"){
            loadData('subSubCat',subCat_id);
        }else{
            $("#subSubCat_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select Sub Sub Category</option>");       
        }
    }

    function loadData(loadType,loadId){
        var dataString = 'loadType='+ loadType +'&loadId='+ loadId;
        $("#"+loadType+"_loader").show();
        $("#"+loadType+"_loader").fadeIn(400).html('Please wait... <img src="image/loading.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "loadData.php",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function(result){
                $("#"+loadType+"_loader").hide();
                $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").html("<option value='-1'>Select "+loadType+"</option>");  
                $("#"+loadType+"_dropdown").append(result);  
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: If you want to get values instead of IDs when you post, you need to create your selects like so `$HTML.="<option value='".$row['1']."'>".$row['1']."</option>";` but I find it more interesting to use the ID instead of the name.

Comment: There is most definitely a way to only post the relevant Js and effected Markup instead of this wall of code... no?

Comment: @teeyo it only post sub category text but sub sub category was not working.

Comment: @GoldPearl yes because that's another select `<?php
                while($rowCategory=mysql_fetch_array($resCategory)){
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rowCategory['category']?>"><?php echo $rowCategory['category']?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>`

if that's what you want I can write you an answer with better formating lol

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Anyway, much more reliable to search by ID, in case of duplicate text or encoding issues etc. It's not impossible that two different countries could have states/regions with the same name. Also a DB query using a numeric ID will be quicker than a text match. The text description of the country is only of interest to the human user. The DB and code should care only about the ID of the row, as that's a unique identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on DB, you must change the type of fields to varchar, so you can set the values as string (usa or other country) instead of numbers.   set the field "category" as foreing key in sub category table...

set AI in each table, so you can make queries about countries and cities name...

Comment: only the affected tables or fields... in your case, in the table case_category: you must set the field id as AI, so the query: INSERT INTO `case_category` ( `category`) VALUES ('USA');

Comment: on the other hand, use json encode in php to get reponse from ajax and build html on javascript...

Comment: finally, query on sub category table:  INSERT INTO `case_sub_category` ( `sub_category`, `category_id`) VALUES
('Florida', 'USA);... so other queries as select will be easier...